# Next.js response data missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I don't really know what is exactly wrong with my code, which does not show the data fetched on my website. When I use `console.log(data)` it fetches the data without any problem, but when I write `src={data.img1}` it does not show anything.

```js
 async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/games");

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}

const Games = async () => {
  const data = await getData();
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Image src={data.img1} alt="..." width={500} height={500} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Games;
```

How can I view the returned data?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to handle API call and return JSX based on API data.

You need to use `useEffect` hook to call API on mount and `useState` hook to store the data in state.

Below is the implementation of the same

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

const getData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/games");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  } else {
    const games = res.json();
    setData(games);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);

return (
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Image src={data?.img1} alt="..." width={500} height={500} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```